# ¿Porqué no cambia nada al moverme entre ramas de Git?

Tags: git

Aprendiendo a usar Git, veo en tutoriales que usan ramas y al cambiar entre ellas el código que ven se modifica y a mí eso no me pasa.
Uso VsCode con extensión de Git, donde me muestra las ramas, el estado, etc. Puedo manipular todo desde su consola como el bash de Git. Pero creo una rama nueva, me muevo a esa rama, realizo cambios y vuelvo a master y se comporta como si siempre trabajara sobre una única rama, no importa cuántas veces me cambie.
Tengo varios archivos y estoy implementando Git en un proyecto avanzado con miles de líneas de código, no creo que tenga relación pero no entiendo porqué moverme entre ramas no genera nada en el IDE.

Comment: Al crear una rama nueva los cambios que realices se reflejarán en ella. ¿Has mirado la pestaña "Control de código fuente" en el desplegable llamado "Cambios"? Allí se reflejan los cambios que están pendientes. Además, ¿estás fusionando la rama con `master` tras terminar de trabajar con la rama de trabajo? ¿Podrías ser más específico con algo que hayas hecho en particular para reproducirlo y explicarte qué te está ocurriendo?

Comment: Lo que creo que está sucediendo es que te estás moviendo entre las ramas _sin haber acometido_ los cambios que hiciste. Esto se puede verificar facilmente. En la pregunta, incluye la salida de `git status` antes de moverte a una rama y luego de moverte a una rama. Si es el caso que estoy diciendo, eso no es un bug. Eso es un feature (y tiene algunas condiciones para funcionar). Una vez que hagas un commit de esos cambios en una de las ramas, cuando te muevas entre ellas, podrás ver que los archivos cambian.

Comment: Gracias por su comentarios. Me he manejado con el Bash de Git y funciona perfecto, tal cuál lo esperado. En VsCode cambio de rama sin problemas pero nunca me pide commit y tampoco sucede nada, en cambio en el bash de git me obliga a comitear, y si no lo hago no cambia de rama, entonces al hacerlo se actualiza el código según la rama en la que estoy.
Puede ser ese el problema, pero bueno, desinstalo la extensión de VsCode y me manejo con el bash de Git y listo

Comment: Bueno, en general el git (de consola) es una herramienta mucho mas poderosa que cualquier plugin de cualquier IDE o cualquier otra herramienta gráfica, así que si es lo que estás usando, kudos para ti. En todo caso, no me suena lo de que git te exija acometer los cambios si vas a cambiar de rama. Eso sucede _si_ alguno de los archivos modificados es diferente entre `HEAD` y el sitio al que quieres moverte. Si todos los archivos que modificaste están igual entre `HEAD` y a donde quieres ir, git te debería dejar mover sin problemas trayendo las modificaciones que tengas aplicadas a donde vayas.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que VsCode crea y modifica constantemente archivos de configuración dentro de mi proyecto que Git los está captando, pero que no son necesario y yo no tenía incorporados en el .gitignore. Por ejemplo, el archivo que hace referencia al espacio de trabajo contiene datos de hasta qué parte del código tengo contraído y cuáles no, entonces eso se edita constantemente, incluso, siempre me crea otros archivos que desconozco pero con terminación .cpython-38.pyc